# How to convert this graph into a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

[image]

Can this graph be converted to some function like $f(x)=x^2+2$ ? Not a sequence of

equations like $f(x)=\{-1<x<0:2, 0<x<1:-x+2, 1<x<2:x, 2<x<3:2\}$?

BTW: I am trying to find the Fourier Transform of this function. So that once I have the function I can use the formula to get the Fourier Transform of function.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you could (with a lot of effort) write down something that you would preferably recognize as function. However, I recommend you to get familiar with piecewise defined functions, as this is the "correct" way to "convert" this graph, and it is nothing wrong about functions defined in this way except maybe some aesthetic concerns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recognise this function as the minimum of $|x - 1| + 1$ (the dip in the middle) and the constant function $2$, so
$$f(x) = \min\{|x - 1| + 1, 2\}.$$
If the minimum function is objectionable, then we can always write minima in terms of absolute values. Recall that
$$\min\{a, b\} = \frac{a + b - |a - b|}{2},$$
hence
$$f(x) = \frac{|x - 1| + 3 - ||x - 1| - 1|}{2}.$$
Ah, but absolute values are themselves defined piecewise. We can get around this using the fact that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, giving us
$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2} + 3 - \sqrt{(\sqrt{(x - 1)^2} - 1)^2}}{2}.$$
And yet, despite my efforts to simplify the expression, we've somehow arrived at an expression that is much, much worse to integrate.

Instead, to compute the Fourier transform, simply split the integral up into four parts. We have
\begin{align*}
\hat{f}(\xi) &= \int_{-1}^3 f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{-1}^0 f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^1 f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_1^2 f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_2^3 f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{-1}^0 2e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^1 (2 - x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_1^2 xe^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_2^3 2 e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
all of which are easily computable directly or with one application of integration by parts. Compare this with simplifying the integral
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-1}^3 \frac{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2} + 3 - \sqrt{(\sqrt{(x - 1)^2} - 1)^2}}{2} e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Take your pick.

Comment: After the FT, I got $\frac{1+e^{-2iw}-2i*we^{jw}+2i*we^{-3iw}-2e^{-iw}}{w^2}$, but the questions is asking me to find X(0), which, when omega is zero. I am not sure the transform is right or not... I am doing right?

Comment: @markable What is the definition of the FT that you're using?

Comment: Angular frequency one.

Comment: @markable I'm afraid I'm not well-versed in these things. My answer is fairly basic. Maybe you could ask another question, including the specific definition you're using, someone can help you verify your answer.